# Run rollup plugin when everything on build is finished

Tags: javascript, build-tools, rollupjs

I use the `experimentalCodeSplitting: true` feature of rollup 0.61.2 to get nice code splitting. Because my project consists also of assets I created a plugin which copies and minifies the asset files accordingly. The problem is that the hooks I used are called for every chunk which is created. Therefore the assets are copied and minified multiple time. The only workaround I found is, to create some flag which is set to `true` after everything is done correctly. Is there a functionality to call a rollup hook after everything (or before everything) is finished and not on every `chunk`? Now my plugin looks something like the following code (I removed some parts and simplified for readability):

```js
export default function copy(userOptions = {}) {
    const name = 'copyAndMinify';
    const files = userOptions.files || [];
    let isCopyDone = false;

    return {
        name: name,
        // also tried onwrite, ongenerate, buildEnd and generateBundle
        buildStart() { 
            if (isCopyDone) {
                return;
            }
            for (let key in files) {
                const src = key;
                const dest = files[key];

                try {
                    minifyFile(src, dest);
                } catch (err) {
                    fatal(name, src, dest, err);
                }
            }
            isCopyDone = true;
        }
    };
};
```

Maybe there is a better way of doing this kind of stuff because with this implementation I always have to completely restart rollup to execute my plugin

Answer (score 5):

The [rollup site](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#generatebundle) lists all the available plugin hooks.

`generateBundle` seems like what you'd want.

> `generateBundle` (formerly `onwrite` and `ongenerate`) - a `( outputOptions, bundle, isWrite ) => void` function hook called when `bundle.generate()` or `bundle.write()` is being executed; you can also return a Promise. bundle provides the full list of files being written or generated along with their details.

Comment: the link is now broken

Comment: Updated with current URL